# ergonomic mouse recomendations

Tags: mouse, hardware-rec, ergonomics

I've searched the site and did not find this exact question asked, so I'm going to ask it.  Does anyone have a recommendation, or can point in the direction of resources, for a good ergonomic mouse?  Specifically a mouse that is designed to support the hand and offer some relief from wrist and hand strain.

Comment: What are your criterias? Why do you need "ergonomic" exactly? Without more details, all I can say is that this question is a duplicate of this one: http://superuser.com/questions/2198/mouse-recommendation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find this a funny answer But seriously.
Get a good seating position. (not an expensive chair)
Most important in the whole ergonomics of a desk job is regular movement(don't be a zombie but change your position)

For the rest, all ergonomics are standard things that have been said before everywhere. And pretty much everybody knows in the back of their head. And just listen to your body.

And about the mouse ;)
Just go somewhere and hold them, the one that fits is probably the best for you.
If however your asking this because something hurts in your body. Don't get a left or right handed mouse but get one you can use with both hands and change mouse hand for a while. This also helps sitting more active since you will get annoyed faster ;)

Good luck with your mouse.

Answer (score 3):

Your local computer shop.

Seriously, what works for one person may not work for you - they're all very different (I use an ergonomic trackball, so does a colleague but they're nothing alike).  Go and experiment with them until you find one that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this multitude](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mouse+trackball+ergonomic) of questions and answers on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) - there's a lot of opinions there.

Comment: Or even closer: http://superuser.com/search?q=mouse+ergonomics

Comment: None of those seem to address the specific question I asked.  Those seem to be more about personal preference rather than ergonomics.

Comment: @Zachary: One and the same. What you find comfy, I may not.

Comment: @Zachary - Also, what "specific" question? You asked only about "a good ergonomic mouse", without any more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Logitech G3. Great shape, good button placement, adjustable weight, and cool braided cord